# How to go through odd index of an array using foreach loop?

Tags: perl, foreach

I want to access `$Array[$i]` and `$Array[$i+1]` in every iteration of `foreach` loop , I think I need to do this

```
$index = 0;
foreach $element (@Array)
{
  // access $element
  // access $Array[$index+1] 

  $index++;
}
```

but if I do in this way , the `i+1` iteration will go through again, But if I want to let the loop go through i , i+2 , i+4 , i+6 ... How can I do?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(my $i=0; $i<scalar(@Array)-1; $i+=2) {
     my $ele1 = $Array[$i];
     my $ele2 = $Array[$i+1];
```